# meteor Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined

Tags: meteor

I'm getting the following error - Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined

I am running meteor under windows(meteor version 0.8.3).

The code is in my templates js file.

```
Tracker.autorun(function (c) {
    if (MovieTrailers.find().fetch().length == 0)
        return;

    c.stop();
    PlayCurrentTrailer();
});
```

So far I have tried :

```
meteor add deps
```

But that didn't work.

Is tracker available under 0.8.3?  or am I missing a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tracker` is the new name of `deps`, so replace the occurrence of `tracker` in your code with `deps` and you're good to go.

Try to avoid running older versions of Meteor to develop new code, can't you run a VM or use an online service like Nitrous.io for development purpose, as deploying a Meteor app to production in a Windows environment for the moment is not going to happen anytime soon ?

Comment: seems that the windows release is pretty far behind.  i have given developing meteor a shot under cloud9, but it is crawlingly slow to use the web ide.  i guess i could go and setup vms, sambas and everything else needed.  its a shame there is little windows love

Comment: Meteor has now been officially released for Windows.